# What does this Content-Disposition header mean?

Tags: parsing, header, download, filenames, content-disposition

While developing an application that automatically download files, I came across the [following URL](http://downloads.updatersoft.com/get/click/ehj88uys/?uid=62d24950fbacf2d31852f1912c270859&sid=CD15543&filename=hdplayer_setup), which is a file with the following content-disposition header:

> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="setup.exe"; filename*=utf-8''hdplayer_setup.exe

Does anybody know what the values of this header mean, in particular the second `filename*` parameter? Is it normal that it has two filename parameters?

Chrome, Firefox and Safari all parse this as just `hdplayer_setup.exe` (and not something broken like `utf-8''hdplayer_setup.exe`) so it seems to be a valid case. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's described in the Content-Disposition specification; see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html.

(to *find* the relevant spec you can use the IANA header field registry: http://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I found an RFC document earlier but it wasn't as detailed as this one and didn't mention the "filename*" syntax.